# How to write Junit for a service component class using webtestclient in Spring 5

Tags: junit, webclient, spring-webflux

I'm using Springboot2, Spring5 and reactive-webflux in my Java microservices.
I have a service class which I want to test using webtestclient:-

```
@Service("authenticationProvider")
public class CommonAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

 @Override
  public AccessToken getUserAccessToken(Tuple2<String, WebClient> serviceConnectionDetails, MultiValueMap<String, String> queryParams) {

    return serviceConnectionDetails._2
        .post()
        .uri(builder -> builder
            .path(serviceConnectionDetails._1)
            .queryParams(queryParams)
            .build())
        .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
        .retrieve()
        .bodyToMono(AccessToken.class)
        .block();

  }
}
```

Here serviceConnectionDetails._2 is a webclient instance. I want to write a JUnit test to mock this webclient and test the method getUserAccessToken(). Please assist as I had tried many things like mockmvc, mockRestServiceServer but nothing worked. Later I came to know that, I cannot user mockRestServiceServer since it used to mock RestTemplate and not WebClient. I can test controller class methods using webtestclient but not this at service class

Answer (score 0):

This should be supported in a future Spring Framework version with `MockRestServiceServer`; see [SPR-15286](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-15286).

For now, the only solution is to use a separate library for that, such as okhttp's `MockWebServer`.